# Having a problem with accessing my public class in other files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn C# from a book and I'm trying to access my public class from this file:

```
public class Character
{
    public string name;
    public int exp = 0;

    public Character(string name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

in this file:

```
public class HeroInfo : MonoBehaviour
 
{
    void Start()
    {
        Character hero = new Character();
        Debug.LogFormat("Hero: {0} - Experience {1}", hero.name, hero.exp);
    }
}
```

In the second file when I try to access "Character", it doesn't show up at all making me unable to use it.

I expected for "Character" to be accessible in the second file as a variable, yet as visible, it didn't really work.

I'm sorry if I didn't format this post properly, yet it's my first and probably not last post on this site.

Comment: you might not add namespace by using "using" keyword at the top if it's different sub or another directory.

Comment: when you return to unity console, are there any errors?

Comment: "Assets\New Folder\HeroInfo.cs(9,30): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'Character.Character(string)'"
That's the only error appearing

Comment: Well, as the error says, you are not calling the constructor correctly. You need something like `Character hero = new Character("Bob");` instead

Comment: Thank you UnholySheep, that helped me, I'm apparently an idiot, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've missed a default constructor. Here how you can fix it:

```
public class Character
{
    // Add a default constructor
    public Character() {}

    public Character(string name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Or you should use it passing the `name` parameter: `Character hero = new Character("some name");`.

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the second file you need to add the namespace of the first file - should be the file that contains your Character class.
Then is better if you also create the empty constructor!